# Why is my sigmoid layer blocking gradients?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, gradient-descent

```
import torch
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn as nn

input = torch.tensor([1.,2.], requires_grad=True)
sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

interm = sigmoid(input)

optimizer = optim.SGD([input], lr=1, momentum=0.9)

for epoch in range(5):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss = torch.linalg.vector_norm(interm - torch.tensor([2.,2.]))
    print(epoch, loss, input, interm)

    loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
    optimizer.step()
    print(interm.grad)
```

So I created this simplified example with an **input** going into a sigmoid as an intermediate activation function.

I am trying to find the **input** that results in **interm** =  [2.,2.]

But the gradients are not passing through. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grads are computed for leaf tensors. In your example, `input` is a leaf tensor, while `interm` is not.

When you try to access `interm.grad`, you should get the following error message:

`UserWarning: The .grad attribute of a Tensor that is not a leaf Tensor is being accessed. Its .grad attribute won't be populated during autograd.backward(). If you indeed want the .grad field to be populated for a non-leaf Tensor, use .retain_grad() on the non-leaf Tensor. If you access the non-leaf Tensor by mistake, make sure you access the leaf Tensor instead. See github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/30531 for more informations. (Triggered internally at aten/src/ATen/core/TensorBody.h:486.)`

This is because grads are propagated back to the leaf tensor `input`, not to `interm`. You can add `interm.retain_grad()` if you want to get the grad for the `interm` variable.

However, even if you did this, there is nothing in your example that would cause the value of `interm` to change. Each optimizer step changes the `input` value, but this does not result in `interm` being recomputed. If you want `interm` to be updated, you need to recompute it each iteration with the new `input` value. ie:

```py
for epoch in range(5):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    interm = sigmoid(input)
    interm.retain_grad()
    loss = torch.linalg.vector_norm(interm - torch.tensor([2.,2.]))
    print(epoch, loss, input, interm)

    loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
    optimizer.step()
    print(interm.grad)
```

There's also a fundamental problem with what you are trying to do. You say you want the `input` that results in `interm = [2., 2.]`. However, you are computing `interm = sigmoid(input)`. The sigmoid function is bounded between `(0, 1)`. There is no such value of `input` that would result in `interm = [2., 2.]`, because `2` is outside the range of the sigmoid function. If you ran your optimization loop indefinitely, you would get `input = [inf, inf]` and `interm = [1., 1.]`.

Comment: thanks, I assumed the optimizer was changing the values of all the intermediate variables as well as the input.